# Adding exception annotation in Phpunit

Tags: phpunit, exception

I'm using `assertContains()` method and I want to add an exception because during the test, if this return false it's stopped and not running the second test.

I followed the PhpUnit documentation but I really don't understand exactly how can I apply those exceptions.

Any one can give some examples?